# Simple docker container fails to run with no indication

Tags: dockerfile, docker-container

This is the contents of my dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:jessie 

RUN    mkdir -p /var/www/html && \
                       mkdir -p /var/log && \
                       mkdir -p /var/lib/mysql && \
                       mkdir -p /etc/apache2/sites-enabled && \
                       chmod 0777 /var/lib/mysql

VOLUME ["/var/www/html", "/var/log", "/var/lib/mysql", "/etc/apache2/sites-enabled"]
```

Run with:

```
docker run --name data \
-v ~/test/www/:/var/www/html \
-v ~/test/logs/:/var/log \
-v ~/test/vhosts/:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled \
-v ~/test/mysql/:/var/lib/mysql \
deano87/dockerfiles:data
```

And it fails to start up. There is nothing printed out anywhere. I have a far more complicated docker image built and running. I followed the same process to build and run etc. I don't see why this one simply fails for no apparent reason?

Comment: Shouldn't there be a *process* too in the container?

Comment: Should there be? Like a RUN command? I had a few RUN commands that simply created directories. What am I missing?

Comment: When the container is built, what process do you want to be left running? What is the container *for* ?

Comment: Apparently it's purpose is to share data. I previously commented out this line from the dockerfile: VOLUME ["/var/www/html", "/var/log", "/var/lib/mysql", "/etc/apache2/sites-enabled"]

Comment: Some other container then references this container using "--volumes-from"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a 'data volume container', see [Creating and mounting a data volume container](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#creating-and-mounting-a-data-volume-container). You only **create** such a container, you do not actually run it, as there is nothing to run. Is just file system.

Comment: Intriguing. So I need not run any "run" command on this container whatsoever? The command I was given to run this container has 4 -v options...

Comment: Post the exact docker file and command(s). Simplify it until the minimum that still reproes. Nobody can answer on hearsay. [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Posted everything now.

Comment: I tried that and the image runs fine. There is no process, of course, as expected, so `docker ps` has nothing to show. But the volumes map fine, container `data` exists etc etc.

Comment: So the run command is necessary? I guess I'm just trying to understand why it's necessary when it does not result in a running container

Comment: It is necessary. The container 'runs'. there is no process in the container, so no code actually 'runs', but the Docker infrastructure has made the container (the cgroup, the namespaces, the port mappings, the volume mappings etc).

Comment: Ok great. Thanks for the helpful explanation :)